# Rails api to an existing web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an existing rails application where the users can register, login and do a few activities. Now I want this to be done through an api so that this it could be used from some kind of external app like for an ios or android application.

I have doubts on how to approach this. I have before created versioned apis and also secured them with the technique of uuids for each user. But here, I already have validations for the user model which validates his email, password and stuffs. I dont think that would be a rightful approach when it comes to the api, specially for a mobile app user to be entering a password to register is not the common practise I think. If some one could suggest an idea where the api could be integrated with the existing application logic and let me know how to bypass these validations, it would be of great help.

Comment: why would a mobile user not have a password to register for your site?

Comment: The mobile user is not registering to the site. He is registering the application. The website is just one part of the application which I have already built. The mobile user registers to the application through an api which requires some authentication. Whether it should be a password is my doubt.